# NullPointerException in invokeSuspend

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception, viewmodel, invoke, tablet

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException:
at com.app.example.sampleClass.BaseViewModel$getList$1.invokeSuspend(BaseViewModel.java:125)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(BaseContinuationImpl.java:8)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.java:100)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)

```
`val viewModelJob = Job()
val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)

uiScope.launch {
   // using looping in this code
}`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

You should get error information as much as possible.

In the error section, the value of something is defined as a type rather than `null`, which means that it actually appeared to be `null`.

If you can make that variable type `null`, do so; otherwise, make sure that it does not enter `null` somehow. And you have to use try catch to catch errors. If the first option is possible, the first option seems to be better.

I hope you understand. If it doesn't work out, try posting more related codes together.

Comment: I cannot do the try catch function. So kindly refer any other way...